# How can we handle large matrices in matlab(larger than 10000x10000)

Tags: matlab, large-data-volumes

In my program I am faced with some matrices that are larger than 10000x10000.
I cannot transpose or inverse them, how can this problem be overcome?

```
??? Error using ==> ctranspose
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
Error in ==> programname1 at 70
    B = cell2mat(C(:,:,s))'; 
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
Example 1: Run the MEMORY command on a 32-bit Windows system:


    >> memory
    Maximum possible array:             677 MB (7.101e+008 bytes) *
    Memory available for all arrays:   1602 MB (1.680e+009 bytes) **
    Memory used by MATLAB:              327 MB (3.425e+008 bytes)
    Physical Memory (RAM):             3327 MB (3.489e+009 bytes)

    *  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
    ** Limited by virtual address space available.

Example 2: Run the MEMORY command on a 64-bit Windows system:

    >> memory
    Maximum possible array:               4577 MB (4.800e+009 bytes) *
    Memory available for all arrays:      4577 MB (4.800e+009 bytes) *
    Memory used by MATLAB:                 330 MB (3.458e+008 bytes)
    Physical Memory (RAM):                3503 MB (3.674e+009 bytes)
```

==============================================================================

```
 memory
% Maximum possible array:            1603 MB (1.681e+009 bytes) *
% Memory available for all arrays:   2237 MB (2.346e+009 bytes) **
% Memory used by MATLAB:              469 MB (4.917e+008 bytes)
% Physical Memory (RAM):             3002 MB (3.148e+009 bytes)


I have used sparse for C. 

B = cell2mat(C);
clear C       %#  to reduce the allocated RAM
P=B\b;

Name         Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes     

  B         5697x5697            584165092  double    sparse, complex
  C         1899x1899            858213576  cell                     
  b         5697x1                   91152  double    complex        

==============================================================================
??? Error using ==> mldivide
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> programname at 82
    P=B\b; 

==============================================================================
```

Edit: 27.05.11

```
Name         Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes

  C          997x997             131209188  cell   
  B            2991x2991             71568648  single    complex        
  Bdp          2991x2991            143137296  double    complex        
  Bsparse      2991x2991            156948988  double    sparse, complex

  Bdp=double(B);
  Bsparse=sparse(Bdp);
```

I used single precision, witch gave the same accuracy as in double precision

It's better, Am I right?

Comment: use a 64 bit system with lots of RAM?

Comment: Mitch is right; what are your memory parameters now? (I assume these aren't sparse matrices, right?)

Comment: I use 32-bit . The matrices are complex symmetric and  2/3 of it's elements are zero. lots of RAM! I have a Intel Core 2 Solo Processor 1.4 Ghz and 3 GM RAM. I think it's alot!! am I right? ;-)

Comment: Can you get away with single() if you're not already?

Comment: @Abolfazi: If 2/3 of its elements are zero, why don't you use sparse matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. If possible, as @yoda suggested, use sparse matrices
2. Do you really need the inverse? If you're solving a linear system (`Ax=b`), you should use MATLAB's [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mrdivide.html).
3. If you really need huge dense matrices, you can harness the memory of several machines using [distributed arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/f1-6010.html#f1-6358) and [MATLAB distributed computing server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/).

Comment: Max size of **B** shoud be 469MB? I think remains only the 3rd one.

Comment: Edited in 27.05.11, with single precition the size of matrices reduced greatly.

Answer (score 1):

3GB isn't alot when each matrix you have is 600 MB all by it's self.  If you can't make the algorithmic changes, you need 64-bit matlab on a 64-bit OS, with alot more RAM.  It's the only way to get alot of memory.  Notice that with 3 GB, Matlab only has 2.2 GB, and the largest chunk is 1.5 GB - that's only 2 of your matricies.

Comment: This is a light scattering problem in DDA method.
If the N dipoles were located at arbitrary positions rj,
then the 9N^2 elements of A would be nondegenerate.
Storage of these elements (with 8 bytes/complex number)
would require 72(N/10^3 )2 Mbytes. By locating the
dipoles on a lattice, the elements of A become highly
degenerate, since they depend only on the displacement
rj - ri. As a result the memory requirements depend
approximately linearly on N rather than on N^2 .

Comment: The program DDSCAT has a total memory requirement of
-0.58(NxNyNz/1000)Mbytes, where Nx X Ny X Nz is
the rectangular volume containing all the N dipoles
   
[1]B. T. Draine and P. J. Flatau,Vol. 11, No. 4/April 1994/J. Opt. Soc. Am. A

Comment: I some paper  perform the calculation with single precision, witch give the same accuracy as in double precision. They also use FFT techniques that evaluate in O(N Ln N) operations rather than
in the O(N^2) operations that are required for general
matrix-vector multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has an easy way to handling huge matrices of orders like 1000000*1000000.
These matrices are usually sparse matrices and it's not necessary to allocate RAM memory for matrix elements of zero value.
So you should just use this command:

A=sparse(1000000,1000000);  "Defining  a 1000000 by 1000000 matrix of zeroes."

Then you can set the diagonal nonzero elements by commands like "spdiags".
See this Link : http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html

Note that you can not use "inv" command to invert matrix A, because "inv" made a normal matrix and uses a lot of space of the RAM.(probably with "out of memory" error)

To solve an equation like A*X=B, you can use X=A\B.